# goolge api error { domain: 'androidpublisher', reason: 'noApks', message: 'This app has no APKs.' }

Tags: google-api, apk

I followed the link here http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/2015/12/26/using-nodejs-to-upload-app-to-google-play.html to use node to upload apk to googleapi. I always got this error

```
errors: 
[ { domain: 'androidpublisher', 
    reason: 'noApks', 
    message: 'This app has no APKs.' } ]
```

This is my upload function

```
function upload(data) {
  var edit = data.edit;
  var apk = data.apk;
  console.log("upload" + edit.data.id);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    play.edits.apks.upload({
      editId: edit.data.id,
      media: {
       mimeType: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
       body: apk
     }
   }, function(err, res) {
      if(err || !res) {
      reject(err);
   }

   resolve(_.omit(_.extend(data, { uploadResults: res }), 'apk'));
  });
 });
}
```

Anyone know what the error is and how to fix it?